# How to use "find" to add a condition in "sumproduction" in Excel forrmual

Tags: excel-formula

I have two `columns`, one "`floor`", floor can be written as an integer or a string "4-5" means 2 floors between 4F and 5F, then another is price, I need to "`SUMPRODUCT`" all the price for all floors.
I do not want to use hidden columns to help the calcuate, only one formula in the totle price cell.

[image: the capture]

have tried `find`,`search`,`match`,`vlookup` for this but get error `#VALUE`

this the formula I written in "`find`".

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(K45:K59,(NOT(ISERROR(INT(H45:H59))))*1)+IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("-",H45:H59))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H45:H59,1,FIND("-",H45:H59)-1)))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H45:H59,FIND("-",H45:H59)+1,LEN(H45:H59)))))),INT(MID(H45:H59,FIND("-",H45:H59)+1,LEN(H45:H59)))-INT(MID(H45:H59,1,FIND("-",H45:H59)-1))+1,0)
```

Comment: sorry, i have something wrong in my formula, I am now correcting it.

Comment: the formula is totally wrong, "find" can not use rang of cells as parameter.

Comment: If you want us to help you with an **absurdly** long formula you need to give us more background - what is your formula trying to do? show us how you've set your worksheet up. FYI it's no wonder you're struggling to get it to work; when you create such a long formula it's much harder to find *where* the error is.

Comment: I am trying to make a dynamic sheet that can be add/remove blocks of rows by VBA, and when a block of rows was added, those formulas in cells will be refresh automatically by excel natural, and this is one of the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` for this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
  IF(ISNUMBER(H$45:H$59),
     1,
     MID(H$45:H$59,FIND("-",H$45:H$59)+1,10)-MID(H$45:H$59,1,FIND("-",H$45:H$59)-1)+1
  ),
  I$45:I$59
)
```

Enter it as an array formula:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Output**
[image]

Comment: `MID(H$45:H$59,FIND("-",H$45:H$59)+1,10)` the last **10** why it is fixed?

Comment: 10 was an arbitrary number, which ensured that the remainder of the string was being captured.  For your example data, the number 2 would have sufficed.  Some people may check the length of the string to grab only what's needed, but that's unnecessary and may actually be slower.

Answer (score 0):

I finally gave up the attempt of writing a single smart formula. because the row count of block is fixed, I divide the formula into a long-but-similar formula.

```
=(IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("-",H45))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H45,1,FIND("-",H45)-1)))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H45,FIND("-",H45)+1,LEN(H45)))))),(INT(MID(H45,FIND("-",H45)+1,LEN(H45)))-INT(MID(H45,1,FIND("-",H45)-1))+1)*K45,K45))+(IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("-",H46))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H46,1,FIND("-",H46)-1)))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H46,FIND("-",H46)+1,LEN(H46)))))),(INT(MID(H46,FIND("-",H46)+1,LEN(H46)))-INT(MID(H46,1,FIND("-",H46)-1))+1)*K46,K46))+(IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("-",H47))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H47,1,FIND("-",H47)-1)))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H47,FIND("-",H47)+1,LEN(H47)))))),(INT(MID(H47,FIND("-",H47)+1,LEN(H47)))-INT(MID(H47,1,FIND("-",H47)-1))+1)*K47,K47))+(IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("-",H48))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H48,1,FIND("-",H48)-1)))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H48,FIND("-",H48)+1,LEN(H48)))))),(INT(MID(H48,FIND("-",H48)+1,LEN(H48)))-INT(MID(H48,1,FIND("-",H48)-1))+1)*K48,K48))+(IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("-",H49))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H49,1,FIND("-",H49)-1)))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H49,FIND("-",H49)+1,LEN(H49)))))),(INT(MID(H49,FIND("-",H49)+1,LEN(H49)))-INT(MID(H49,1,FIND("-",H49)-1))+1)*K49,K49))+(IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("-",H50))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H50,1,FIND("-",H50)-1)))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H50,FIND("-",H50)+1,LEN(H50)))))),(INT(MID(H50,FIND("-",H50)+1,LEN(H50)))-INT(MID(H50,1,FIND("-",H50)-1))+1)*K50,K50))+(IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("-",H51))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H51,1,FIND("-",H51)-1)))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H51,FIND("-",H51)+1,LEN(H51)))))),(INT(MID(H51,FIND("-",H51)+1,LEN(H51)))-INT(MID(H51,1,FIND("-",H51)-1))+1)*K51,K51))+(IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("-",H52))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H52,1,FIND("-",H52)-1)))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H52,FIND("-",H52)+1,LEN(H52)))))),(INT(MID(H52,FIND("-",H52)+1,LEN(H52)))-INT(MID(H52,1,FIND("-",H52)-1))+1)*K52,K52))+(IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("-",H53))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H53,1,FIND("-",H53)-1)))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H53,FIND("-",H53)+1,LEN(H53)))))),(INT(MID(H53,FIND("-",H53)+1,LEN(H53)))-INT(MID(H53,1,FIND("-",H53)-1))+1)*K53,K53))+(IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("-",H54))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H54,1,FIND("-",H54)-1)))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H54,FIND("-",H54)+1,LEN(H54)))))),(INT(MID(H54,FIND("-",H54)+1,LEN(H54)))-INT(MID(H54,1,FIND("-",H54)-1))+1)*K54,K54))+(IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("-",H55))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H55,1,FIND("-",H55)-1)))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H55,FIND("-",H55)+1,LEN(H55)))))),(INT(MID(H55,FIND("-",H55)+1,LEN(H55)))-INT(MID(H55,1,FIND("-",H55)-1))+1)*K55,K55))+(IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("-",H56))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H56,1,FIND("-",H56)-1)))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H56,FIND("-",H56)+1,LEN(H56)))))),(INT(MID(H56,FIND("-",H56)+1,LEN(H56)))-INT(MID(H56,1,FIND("-",H56)-1))+1)*K56,K56))+(IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("-",H57))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H57,1,FIND("-",H57)-1)))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H57,FIND("-",H57)+1,LEN(H57)))))),(INT(MID(H57,FIND("-",H57)+1,LEN(H57)))-INT(MID(H57,1,FIND("-",H57)-1))+1)*K57,K57))+(IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("-",H58))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H58,1,FIND("-",H58)-1)))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H58,FIND("-",H58)+1,LEN(H58)))))),(INT(MID(H58,FIND("-",H58)+1,LEN(H58)))-INT(MID(H58,1,FIND("-",H58)-1))+1)*K58,K58))+(IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("-",H59))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H59,1,FIND("-",H59)-1)))),NOT(ISERROR(INT(MID(H59,FIND("-",H59)+1,LEN(H59)))))),(INT(MID(H59,FIND("-",H59)+1,LEN(H59)))-INT(MID(H59,1,FIND("-",H59)-1))+1)*K59,K59))
```